# Checking startup files on opening Terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04, system

I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my Dell Laptop.

I see my `.profile` file for current user. It has something like this written,

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
```

However, when I try to open this file,

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:~$ cd  /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/
bash: cd: /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files: No such file or directory
```

I guess the `startup-files` might have moved on to some different path. Please explain 
Where I can see that which files are executed on starting the terminal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `startup-files` mentioned are not part of the standard bash installation, but are provided by a separate `bash-doc` package. If you wish to examine them you will need to install `bash-doc`, either from you favorite GUI package manager or from the command line e.g.

```
sudo apt install bash-doc
```